# Renombrar Grupos de controladores de Swagger

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

estoy diseñando una API en ASP.NET Core5.0, en esta versión del Framework, ya viene Swagger instalado y estoy intentando renombrar los nombres de los grupos de controladores:
[image: Tag controladores]

Pero no encuentro nada que me funcione.
Me podéis echar una mano por favor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el cada controlador debes colocar lo siguiente:

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "Autenticación")]
public class AuthController : ControllerBase
```

Y en el archivo `startup.cs` donde tienes `services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>` adentro debes colocar lo siguiente:

```
c.TagActionsBy(api => api.GroupName);
c.DocInclusionPredicate((name, api) => true);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]